# How create multidimensional array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to create a *multidimensional array* in **c#**, but I`m not sure how. The array should look like this:

```
array1, array2, array3
array4, array5, array6
array7, array8, array9
```

The each small array will store `3` `int`s. I managed to create a multidimensional array that stores `1` array on each line, but I need to store `3` arrays on each line.

**The code** is below:

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[3][];

jaggedArray[0] = new int[] {  1,  3,  5 };
jaggedArray[1] = new int[] {  0,  2,  4 };
jaggedArray[2] = new int[] { 11, 22, 33 };
```

Comment: Wait, do you want a 2d array of arrays, or do you want a jagged array of arrays, or do you want a 3d array?

Comment: Pleas dont copy code from other sites to explain what you want to to and what you already achieve.

Comment: not really sure, I need an array that stores 3 lines of arrays,and on each line I need to store 3 arrays

Comment: Your description is confusing, You want an array stores 3 int, but your posted code contains 5,4,2 int. Please explain desired data structure step by step clearly.

Comment: Do any of your dimensions have varying sizes? Like is [0,0] a 5-entry array, and [0,1] a 10-entry array?

Comment: yes, in each array I will store 3 ints,so there would be total 9 arrays stored in a single array,3 arrays per line,3 rows

Comment: Note that you should mark the most useful answer as accepted. Dmitry's is most likely to be the one you need, I expect.

Answer (score 4):

Your description corresponds to *2d array of arrays* `int[,][]`:

```
 int[] array1 = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
 ... 
 int[] array9 = new int[] {89, 562, 356};

 ...  

 // 2d array of arrays (array1..array9)
 int[,][] array = new int[,][] {
   { array1, array2, array3, },
   { array4, array5, array6, },
   { array7, array8, array9, },  
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare as given below. you can use jagged arrays.

```cs
int[][,] jaggedArray4 = new int[3][,] 
{
    new int[,] { {1,3,3}, {5,7,7},{1,2,3} },
     new int[,] { {1,3,3}, {5,7,7},{1,2,3} },
     new int[,] { {1,3,3}, {5,7,7},{1,2,3} }
};

Console.WriteLine(jaggedArray4[0][1,0]);//displayed first row , 2nd element array's first element
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have 3x3x3, you can use a 3d array:

```
int[,,] my3dArray = new int[3,3,3];
```

And you can access it like so:

```
my3dArray[0,0,0] = 5;
my3dArray[0,0,1] = 2;
my3dArray[1,2,0] = 41;
Console.WriteLine(myArray[1,2,0]); // prints 41
```

If each dimension is a variable size, you could used an array of arrays of arrays (kind of a 3d jagged array):

```
int[][][] myJagged = new int[3][][];
myJagged[0] = new int[3][];
myJagged[0][0] = new int[] {1, 2, 3}; // etc. until you've initialized all the arrays at all levels

Console.WriteLine(myJagged[0][0][2]); // prints 3
```

Alternatively, if only your last dimension is a variable size (or if it's easier to work with), you could use a 2d array of arrays:

```
int[,][] myArray = new int[3,3][];
myArray[0,0] = new int[] { 5, 2, 41 };
Console.WriteLine(myArray[0,0][2]); // prints 41
```